# System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#, base64

Buen día,

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente: Este método que tengo es para obtener una lista de toda la información que se haya registrado, sin embargo, al ingresar para ver tal información, me indica lo siguiente:

> System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

Anexo el método utilizado:

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }

    public override async Task<PagedResultDto<PermisoDto>> GetListAsync(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
    {

        try
        {
            var qPermiso = await Repository.GetQueryableAsync();

            var query = from permiso in qPermiso
                        select new { permiso };

            var base64 = Base64Encode(qPermiso.ToString());

            var queryResult = await AsyncExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

            var perDtos = queryResult.Select(x =>
            {
                var perDtos = ObjectMapper.Map<Permiso, PermisoDto>(x.permiso);
                perDtos.ModalidadPermiso = x.permiso.ModalidadPermiso;
                return perDtos;
            }).ToList();

            var paginationList = (from element in perDtos.AsQueryable() select element).OrderBy(input.Sorting).Skip(input.SkipCount).Take(input.MaxResultCount).ToList();

            var totalCount = await Repository.GetCountAsync();

            return new PagedResultDto<PermisoDto>(totalCount, paginationList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Ocurrio al consultar los permisos: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Por lo que al depurar, el breakpoint se rompe pasando la siguiente línea:

```
var base64 = Base64Encode(qPermiso.ToString());
```

Intente codificar la entrada para no tener un error al ingresar un carácter especial o número, pero aun así me indica la excepción antes mencionada.

Agradecería mucho de sus comentarios y/o alguna referencia para obtener alguna posible solución.

Gracias.

Comment: Y cuál es la entrada? Necesitaremos datos de prueba, no?

Comment: Pregunta, con entrada a que hace referencia, para poder explicarme más mejor? Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el string que estás utilizando? Cuál es el valor de `qPermiso.ToString()`?

Comment: El valor de qpermiso es traer el número de información que este guardada en la tabla

Comment: Tu error se debe a que no puede transformar el string en base64, posiblemente porque tiene un carácter ilegal, por eso te preguntan cuál es exactamente ese string, con el fin de poder ayudarte a depurar. Cuando te preguntan por el valor, es el valor string que tiene esa variable, NO para que sirve. Por otro lado, favor mostrar la función `Repository.GetQueryableAsync()`

Comment: En todo caso, necesitaremos saber EXACTAMENTE cuál es la cadena de texto sobre la que estás intentando utilizar `Base64Encode`

Comment: Veo que `qPermiso` viene de una sentencia `linq to sql`. Si `qPermiso` es un `tipo`, es decir, una clase, el método `.ToString()` puede que te esté devolviendo el [fully qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names) de tu clase. Puede ser algo como `[MadAssemblyName.MadNamespace.Permiso]`, a menos que tengas `protected override string ToString()` dentro de la clase Permiso que te devuelva las propiedades como cadena de texto.

Comment: *El valor de qpermiso es traer el número de información*. Es un valor, no una función. `await Repository.GetQueryableAsync()` hace lo que escribes. Por cierto, depura el código, mira qué cadena está obteniendo y cárgala a la pregunta.